# gradlew :appengineEnhance fails

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, datanucleus

I am creating a mobile backend in Java using `Google App Engine` with `Android Studio`. In order to start the local server exposing my API, I use `gradlew [module name]:appengineRun`.

However, when I go to `http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer`, and try to use the API
I get the following error:

```
apr 29, 2014 10:52:32 PM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
SEVERE: The class "com.mthoresen.fest.backend.LocationBean" is not persistable. 
This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of 
the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the 
Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.
```

In addition, the process never ends - it's stuck at `Building 88% > :[module name]:appengineRun`

---

## Edit

**This mess is solved by loosebazooka's answer, but `appengineRun` still failes with the same error.**

So I tried `gradlew [module name]:appengineEnhance` instead, which gives me the following output:

```
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:backend:appengineDownloadSdk                                                        
:backend:compileJava UP-TO-DATE                                                  
:backend:appengineEnhance FAILED          

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEnhance'.
> An error occurred enhancing DataNucleus classes.

* Try:         
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option  to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

`--info` gives me nothing else, and `--debug` is way to much output. `--stacktrace` doesn't really help either:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task     ':backend:appengineEnhance'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: An error occurred enhancing DataNucleus classes.
    at com.google.appengine.task.EnhanceTask.enhanceClasses(EnhanceTask.groovy:58)
    at com.google.appengine.task.EnhanceTask.executeTask(EnhanceTask.groovy:34)
    at com.google.appengine.task.AbstractTask.start(AbstractTask.groovy:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:533)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:516)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: : Java returned: 1
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:111)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.EnhancerTask.execute(EnhancerTask.java:97)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.nodeCompleted(BasicAntBuilder.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(BasicAntBuilder.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder.super$3$invokeMethod(DefaultAntBuilder.groovy)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder.invokeMethod(DefaultAntBuilder.groovy:37)
    at com.google.appengine.task.EnhanceTask.enhanceClasses(EnhanceTask.groovy:42)
    ... 56 more
```

All documentation I can find from Google is using `Eclipse` with `maven` and `ant`, but `Android Studio` has a `Google App Engine` plugin, so it wouldn't make sense to say it isn't supported.

The java class I want to save:

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Key;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class LocationBean {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    @Persistent
    private double lat;
    @Persistent
    private double lng;
    @Persistent
    private double rad;
    @Persistent
    private long endtime;

    /** Getters and setters */
}
```

Digging in the output from `--debug`, I found the following line:

```
Encountered a problem: Unexpected exception
Please see the logs [C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\enhance4980231719213251330.log] for further information.
```

So I did. This is the logfile:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:76)
at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.<init>(Enhance.java:71)
at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.main(Enhance.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:74)
... 2 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.enhancer" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/Users/Martin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-enhancer/3.1.1/b141c67d55cc19f14639f091b84e692e2198dc50/datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Users/Martin/.gradle/appengine-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.3/lib/opt/tools/datanucleus/v1/datanucleus-enhancer-1.1.4.jar."
at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:541)
at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:395)
at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensions(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:219)
at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensionPoints(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:160)
at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.<init>(PluginManager.java:65)
at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createPluginManager(PluginManager.java:427)
at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:224)
at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:204)
at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.<init>(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:160)
at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1133)
... 7 more
```

The interesting line being

```
Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.enhancer" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL 
"file:/C:/Users/<username>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-enhancer/3.1.1/b141c67d55cc19f14639f091b84e692e2198dc50/datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar" 
is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL 
"file:/C:/Users/<username>/.gradle/appengine-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.3/lib/opt/tools/datanucleus/v1/datanucleus-enhancer-1.1.4.jar."
```

So it looks like two widely different versions of `datanucleus-enhancer` is present. Somehow, gradlew downloads version `3.1.1` (which I have specified in `build.gradle`), while a part of the process wants to use version `1.1.4`. Again, I can't find any resources on how to change this, as every single tutorial on the web are using Maven.

Comment: And the CLASSPATH is ? it defines what is possible to be loaded, and AppEngine often has some jars in WEB-INF or other places.

Comment: How do I know what the CLASSPATH is?

Comment: It tells you that it has included "file:/C:/Users/<username>/.gradle/appengine-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.3/lib/opt/tools/datanucleus/v1/datanucleus-enhancer-1.1.4.jar" so remove that perhaps ... and any other datanucleus-*-1.1 jars

Comment: I tried, but they both somehow gets downloaded by gradle each time i build, like they should. I guess the problem is that something thinks I want to use the `1.1.4` version of the enhancer, even though I want to use 3.1.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update:

This answer has gone a little out of date, if you're using gradle-appengine-plugin version 1.9.5 or higher, you should use the new configuration

```
appengine {
  enhancer {
    version = "v2"
    enhanceOnBuild = true
  }
}
```

instead of what follows below.

### Original Answer:

You probably need to configure the enhancer to use v2 of the enhancer.

in your build.gradle file

```
appengine {
  enhancerVersion = "v2"
}
```

[Edit]
To make enhance run automatically before creating the war

in your build.gradle file

```
war.dependsOn appengineEnhance
```

Comment: This makes `:appengineEnhance` succed, but `:appengineRun` still gives me the same error.

Comment: so appengineEnhance only enhances classes in the intermediate "build/classes" directory before packaging.

I think you might need to do "./gradlew appengineEnhance appengineAssemble" or even add the enhance task as a dependency by adding [war.depends on appengineEnhance] to your build file

Comment: I added the dependency; now I get yet another error message: `com.google.api.server.spi.config.validation.MissingParameterNameException: myApi.com.mthoresen.fest.backend.MyEndpoint.MyEndpoint.jdoProvideField parameter (type int): Missing parameter name. Parameter type (int) is not an entity type and thus should be annotated with @Named.`, which I guess is a method the enhancer created.

Comment: So it probably shouldn't be enhancing your endpoints class.  What annotations do you have on the MyEndpoint class?

Comment: Wow. The class `MyEndpoint` was mistakenly annotated with `@PersistenceCapable`. I removed the annotation, and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problem, but I'm using JPA instead. I've made `:appengineEnhance` run by specifying `api`:

```
enhancer {
    version = "v2"
    api="jpa"  // or jdo
    enhanceOnBuild = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (`"org.datanucleus.enhancer" is already registered`) and i found the solution.

First i've use the code posted by @loosebazooka in my `build.gradle` PLUS:

```
dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.8'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.8'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.8'
    compile 'com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:2.1.2'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'javax.jdo:jdo2-api:2.3-eb'
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jdo:3.1.3' // WE NEED THIS
    //compile 'javax.jdo:jdo-api:3.0.1' // ALREADY IN datanucleus-appengine
    //compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:3.1.4' // ALREADY IN datanucleus-appengine
    //compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-enhancer:3.1.1' // ALREADY IN datanucleus-appengine
}
```

I'm running on `Android Studio 0.8.10`

Now gradle does the `appengine:appengineEnhance` task and the service is up and working!

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution to your problem. But may be helpful for others who get this exception:

```
TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task     ':backend:appengineEnhance'
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: An error occurred enhancing DataNucleus classes.
Caused by: : Java returned: 1
```

It may happen if you have declared an entity class without a primary key.